# Failed to copy container from Azure to Local Emulator

Tags: azure, cmd, azcopy

**scenario**

I would like to copy whole contianer from my storage account at Azure to my local storage account at Storage Emulator. I had SAS token to both accounts generated.
I tried in windows 10 CMD:

```
azcopy copy "https://myazuresrg.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/?
sv=2020-08-04&ss=b&srt=co&sp=rltf&se=2021-09-10T15:14:05Z&st=2021-09-
10T07:14:05Z&spr=https&sig=Eb%2FsK9kmwVDJt2PPg2a6wocXkK7EDrj3fgY8uT5dI
IE%3D" "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/mycontainer?
sv=2019-07-07&sr=c&sig=XXXXXXXX&se=2021-09-11T07%3A29%3A46Z&sp=rwdl" -
-recursive=true --from-to=BlobLocal
```

**Problem**

In logs I can see error:

```
DOWNLOADFAILED:
 https://myazuresrg.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/website/footer.js
on?se=2021-09-10t15%3A14%3A05z&sig=-REDACTED-
&sp=rltf&spr=https&srt=co&ss=b&st=2021-09-10t07%3A14%3A05z&sv=2020-08-
04 : 000 : File Creation Error mkdir \\?
\C:\AzCopy\http:\127.0.0.1:10000\devstoreaccount1\mycontainer?sv=2019-
07-07&sr=c&sig=-REDACTED-&se=2021-09-
11T07%3A29%3A46Z&sp=rwdl\mycontainer\website: The filename, directory 
name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Why Azcopy add prepath `\C:\AzCopy` to my local acount emulator path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. Incorrect use of `--from-to`. Basically you would use `--from-to=BlobLocal` when you want to download the blob from storage to your local computer. That's the reason you're seeing azcopy prepending `\C:\AzCopy` to your local emulator path.
2. You cannot use `azcopy copy` to copy blobs from cloud storage account to your storage emulator. Essentially copy blob operation is an async operation where once you initiate the copy operation, Azure Storage service asynchronously copies the blob from source to destination account. For this both source and target account must be in the cloud. Azure Storage service must be able to reach out to both of these accounts. Considering your target account is storage emulator running on your local computer, Azure Storage service will not be able to reach it and thus copy operation will fail.

What you will need to do in this case is first download the blobs from your storage account to your local computer and then upload it in your storage emulator.